# Neural network outputs extreme probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, neural-networks, overfitting

I currently have two scenarios that I'm unable to understand:

1. A multi-class neural network classifier: this model's final softmax layer outputs very extreme "probabilities" for each class for the samples - very often just 0 or 1, instead of something less extreme (like say 0.8 or 0.2 or whatever).
2. A multi-label neural network classifier that has much the same problem of outputting extreme 0/1 scores, albeit with a sigmoid last layer.

Any idea of what might be going wrong? If this is overfitting -- I'm using quite a bit of dropout too but that didn't help either. How can I remedy this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you scale your inputs? And, how did you initialise the weights?

Comment: @gunes I didn't scale my inputs - I'm using a LSTM with self attention and then 1 hidden dense layer followed by a softmax/sigmoid layer to classify. The kernel initializer is glorot uniform